# Utility to log which applications have been used?

Tags: windows-7, logging

We have a set up with many public PCs with a base installation of Windows 7 and MS Office (plus a few other bits and pieces). A small subset of these also have other applications such as Adobe Creative Suite installed.

In order to see if these apps are being used fully I'm looking for a simple (and cheap/free) way to log basic usage of these particular programs - either just a count to the number of times launched per application or how long the app was in use for.

We specifically don't want to log anything like websites visited (as some of the commercially available software will do) for privacy reasons.

Any suggestions for a way to do this or a utility that would do the job?

Comment: Have you looked into using the Windows Event Log?

Comment: @rrirower Unfortunately the Event Log doesn't seem to record application starts - at least I can't find any references to them

Comment: You'll probably need to create your own event.  [Powershell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/02/01/use-powershell-to-create-and-to-use-a-new-event-log.aspx) provides some nice capabilities to handle that.